# Excel - sum of duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I need formula to consolidate values this way:

Joanna  9, Kate    6, Mary    9, Jack    5, Nina    4, Joanna  3, Kate    2, Joanna  1

to get

**Joanna   13**, **Kate     8**, **Mary     9**, **Jack     5**, **Nina     4**

First list of data is output, in bold is the  result that I want to get.
I can't use neither button consolidate nor pivot but formula.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps which I tried to resolve your issue:-

1. First try to have all these values stored in a column (Remove the delimiters)
2. Then you can try splitting each string using " " (space) as a delimiter and you will have to use the below two formulas to have name and number stored in two different columns: -

   ```
   To Store name use this Formulae :- 
      =LEFT(A1, SEARCH(" ",A1,1)-1)

   What the above function is doing:- Let's consider that SEARCH(" ", A1,1) returns 5, it means that you are only considering the first five characters of the string starting from left.
   ```

   ---

   ```
    Similarly to get the number out of that string we will use the below function:- 

      =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)- SEARCH(" ",A1,1))

   What the above function is doing:- Let's consider that SEARCH(" ", A1,1) returns 5 and the length of the string is 7, it means that you are only considering first (7-5) = 2 characters of the string starting from the right.
   ```

Btw SEARCH(" ", A1, 1) function is used to get the position of delimiter in the string ( Here our delimiter is " " --> Space)

3. Now as you have two columns, one only with names and another only with numbers, now you can do an aggregate sum on these columns and store the value to a different column.

   For this, we can use the below formulae

   ```
     =SUMPRODUCT((B1:B8=B1)*(C1))

   What the above function is doing:- Let's consider that names are present in the B column and the number is present in the C column. So based on names present in column B1 to B8, it will aggregate the sum on the C column and give you the results.
   ```

I built this on my local using the same formula and am pasting the screenshots to give you a better understanding of the process.

[image: Name]
[image: Number]
[image: Aggregation]

I hope this will answer your question Please reach out in the comments if any further clarification is required.

Thanks